# GPIO device detected on Embedded device When connected, but not able to communicate

Tags: embedded, usb, embedded-linux, gpio, cdc

I am trying to communicate to my embedded(set-top box) device through this(http://numato.com/8-channel-usb-gpio-module) GPIO. Previously, when i attached this device to my set top box, then in dmesg, it is showing only that new usb device has been attached and by some hook/crook method, i manually created a node with major minor number of recently attached usb device and through my cross compiled c program, i tried to send gpio commands, which throws me the errors of **invalid commands**. After some more research, i get to know that on my set top box kernel, **ACM CDC** support is disabled. so i compiled the kernel again with CDC ACM support enabled and USB serial convertor support enabled. after flashing the kernel on BOX, now when i attached the device, in dmesg, it is showing that device is attached, New ACM device detected on ttyACM0, but no node is created in **/dev**, instead i found the device info in **/sys/class/tty/ttyACM0**. from here, i get the major and minor number of my device and manually created a node. after that i tried to communicate again, but now, instead of saying invalid command, my program is stuck on the first GPIO command and it is not executing any GPIO commands, but giving me the output of all the printf statements at application layer. please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the code you are using to try to write to it, and explain **exactly** what results.  Also, does this code work with the peripheral on a desktop linux?